# Prestashop redirects 404 pages from http to https. Why?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I've got a problem with Prestashop redirection.

Everytime when someone gets to not existing page via `http`, it first returns 301, redirects to the very same URI but with `https` protocol, and then returns 404.

Shop works mainly on `http`, only cart and user areas are `https`.

Changing `PageNotFoundController.php` gave no results. Nothing suspicious in `.htaccess` and I cannot find any other possible causes. Any ideas how to fix it, or prevent redirecting?

Comment: Your web host has perhaps not configured your domain to https

Comment: @toto21 bu cart, user areas and other pages using SSL work perfectly. Categories using `http` only works fine too. Only non-existing pages gets `http->https` redirect

Comment: So try this in your `.htaccess` : 
`ErrorDocument 404 /yourcustom404page.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you have SSL:

**Step 1.** Log into your PrestaShop dashboard

**Step 2.** Using the top menu bar, hover over the **Preferences** tab and select the **General** option.

**Step 3.** From the **Preferences** : **General** page, find the **Enable SSL** option. If you have an SSL installed on your account for the PrestaShop 1.5 domain name, you will be able toclick on a **Yes** option here, turning on the ability to use SSL on specific pages.

**Step 4.** Click on the **Save** button in the upper right corner to save your SSL configuration.